# Codeigniter Session userdata from the database does not return values

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Hi I am trying to access the timestamp of the current session. I am trying to access its value by using `$this->session->userdata('timestamp');` but it return `NULL`. I have tried `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());` but it seems it only know the variables set by `$this->session->set_userdata('blah', 'blah');`.

Config looks like:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

And it can store the ip_address, timestamp, id of the session in the database but I am trying to find a way to access the values in that database.

For example I have done `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());`

What I will see is an array with the value of 'blah' and not the values stored in the table.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: For getting timestamp of last activity try $this->session->userdata('last_activity');

Answer (score 1):

There's a section of the manual for `CI_Session` that's dedicated to this topic: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#accessing-session-metadata

As you can understand from that link, there's no straightforward way to access the session timestamp. If you're using the database driver, you have to fetch it from the database - there's no other way.

Comment: Thank you sir, I have already found a way to access it using the "session_id()" that is the same as the id of that specific timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$this->session->__ci_last_regenerate
```

or

```
$_SESSION['__ci_last_regenerate']
```

Comment: I think using that has a different value compared to what's stored in the session database table called timestamp

Comment: It is a different value.

Comment: @narf With `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;` as in OP, this could be fairly used?

Comment: No, it can't. The session timestamp tells you when was the last time the session data was accessed, while `__ci_last_regenerate` tells you when it was last generated (or created).

Answer (score -1):

Are you storing the timestamp into the userdata? If yes then only you will get the current timestamp of the session if you want then you need to use following code.

```
$sessionData = $this->session->all_userdata();

SessionData contain following array values and you can use the `last_activity` 
Array
(
    [session_id] => 4a5a5dca22728fb0a84364eeb405b601
    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7;
    [last_activity] => 1303142623
)
```

For more help

> https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: This would only work on CI 2.x and the OP uses version 3+. Also, the official user guide is on codeigniter.com and not on EllisLab's website.

Comment: @Narf User doesn't mention which version he is using

Comment: I didn't say he mentioned it, but he *is* using 3.x. It's obvious by the configuration he posted - CI2 only has half of those settings.